# Angular Dot Net Core 2.0 Build Issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getthing this issue.  I can't even build the Angular template using Dot Net Core/Standard 2.0

I just downloaded the Dotnet core 2.0 and VS 2017 15.3 and followed the wizard to just say hello world.  I downloaded all the package needed from NPM source.

```html
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: AngularApplication2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>AngularApplication2 -> c:\users\wil\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AngularApplication2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\AngularApplication2.dll
1>v4.6.0
1>Performing first-run Webpack build...
1>Hash: 803ac2b1a73d67da6627538031cacab98fa900ef
1>Version: webpack 2.5.1
1>Child
1>    Hash: 803ac2b1a73d67da6627
1>    Time: 5931ms
1>                                   Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
1>    89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
1>                               vendor.js  3.26 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
1>                              vendor.css   315 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
1>Child
1>    Hash: 538031cacab98fa900ef
1>    Time: 5908ms
1>                                   Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
1>    89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
1>                               vendor.js  3.43 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
1>c:\users\wil\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AngularApplication2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:8
1>const { __NGTOOLS_PRIVATE_API_2 } = require('@angular/compiler-cli');
1>      ^
1>
1>SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
1>    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
1>    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
1>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
1>    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
1>    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
1>    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
1>    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
1>    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\wil\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AngularApplication2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:30:10)
1>    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
1>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
1>c:\users\wil\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AngularApplication2\AngularApplication2.csproj(34,5): error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "AngularApplication2.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Check the nodes version: tools-> Extension and Updates. This looks similar: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5364

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Per ? 
I was missing path to the nodejs.

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package management -> External Web Tools. Adding the path to nodejs install folder solved it.

Comment: Hi wil, do you mean to the nodejs executable or where the modules are installed?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I think it was a nodejs link like so "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"  This was added to the Location of external tools

Answer (score 8):

Its a issue with NodeJs Environment Variable,

Please install latest Node js from [Official Website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) will resolve this environment variable setting problem and matches with same values as in latest Visual Studio.

Please rebuild your angular core project will resolve this issue.

Comment: I have ` node --version
v8.11.1` but I still have this problem publishing. Everything works just fine but when I publish I get and error. When I run the command stand-alone I get `ERROR in main-client.js from UglifyJs
    Unexpected token: operator (>) [main-client.js:52912,19]`

Comment: Please make sure you have no issues with npm packages dependencies (versions interdependent) in the packages listed in package.json.

Check console for more error details and root cause.

Comment: The only console output error is from the VS Code terminal window where this is red `.....csproj(41,5): error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.`

Comment: Running the command in error was how I arrived at the "error detail" regarding 'main-client.js' which was also the only error.